# In Objective-C, how to decide which initializer is the designated one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I read some material which says that the designated initializer is the "most complete" initializer in the initializer list.

But for example in `UIView initWithFrame:(CGRect)Frame` and `initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecode` both take 1 parameter, how to decide which one's is the UIView's  designated initializer?

Comment: [The one that the documentation says it is](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/initWithFrame:). (By the way, `initWithCoder:` is not a method of `UIView` but part of a protocol... In this case `initWithCoder:` is to be used when unarchiving from a xib/storyboard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have access to the source, you can recognize the designated initializer as the one that calls `super init` while all the others just call that one either directly or indirectly - assuming the author follows this convention. They might also use the `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` macro to make this explicit (read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW8)). When you don't have access to the source code, as is the case with Apple's classes, then they need to tell you somehow - luckily they do so in the class references - e.g. you can see [in the reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/initWithFrame:) for UIView that `initWithFrame:` is the designated initializer.

Comment: Vinay's point is good too :) Though it seems to vary whether Apple uses NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER or a comment of either the // or /* */ type to note this - I find the documentation a bit more consistent so I don't have to look around for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Command + click the initializer you want to know about. In the documentation it will be mentioned if the initializer is the `designated` or `default` initializer.

For `UIView` default initializer is:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;          // default initializer
```